# protobuff emptyList() is not public in LazyStringArrayList

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-java

proto file

```
  repeated string applicableType = 4;
```

proto generated code

```
applicableType_ =
        com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.emptyList();
```

while compiling the code it shows

```
emptyList() is not public in LazyStringArrayList; cannot be accessed from outside package
        com.google.protobuf.LazyStringArrayList.emptyList();
```

build is getting failed

this method is static and public as well, tried to run on java 17 and 19 as well but still giving error
tried to regenerate proto files as well

Comment: This issue was reported and fixed in version 3.23.0 of protobuf-java. You may need to upgrade your protobuf-java dependency to 3.23.0 or higher to resolve this error.

Comment: thanks @Piroozeh solved the issue. was using     
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.19.6' changed to 
implementation 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:3.24.0'